# Create relations with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I'm doing a simple discussion forum where the user can post something and comment on the posts. There is a flagging option for both the posts and comments. I'm storing both the flags of posts and comments on a same table. So while deleting the post or comment, i also need to delete the flags of them which is stored in the same table. Now how to make the relations in my table so that while deleting posts or comments it should also delete the corresponding flag items also.

Here is the structure of my flag table.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the posts and comments are stored in different tables. If that is the case, you cannot use CASCADE DELETE to delete rows with foreign key.

There are 2 options for you:

1. Do it in the program.
2. Use MySQL trigger.

   create trigger deleteflags
   after delete on post
   for each row
   begin
   delete from flag where faf_item_id = old.id